# Stereoscopic camera with RGBDSLAM

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used stereoscopic camera (calibrated) produce pointcloud images.
Can I mimic these messages as Kinect output messages so I can use RGBDSLAM to generate 3D model?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11333/stereoscopic-camera-with-rgbdslam/) by [rhtmxhq8](https://answers.ros.org/users/1131/rhtmxhq8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2011-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. RGBDSLAM requires the point cloud, and (IIRC) the grayscale camera image; all you'll need to do is get the topic names right, and you should be good to go.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1